# The right data model for a JavaScript object with two primary keys

Tags: javascript, primary-key

I was using a simple associative object to store some locales for my applications:

```
locales.en = {
  'A string': 'My localized string',
  'Another string': 'Another localized string',
  (...)
};
locales.fr = {
  (...)
};
```

Later, I simply use this object like that:

```
var translated = locales.en[toTranslate];
```

Now, I need to add a *context* to some locales and the primary key becomes the locale plus the (optional) context.
I could imagine using a special separator char (like '§' which is usually never used in localization strings), something like that ('in combobox' and 'in a panel header' are contextes):

```
locales.en = {
  'A string§in combobox': 'My localized string',
  'A string§in a panel header': 'My localized string in another context',
  'Another string': 'Another localized string'
};
```

But this solution seems a little tinked to me, I'm wondering if there is another solution...
I could have hundred of locales inside this object.

Comment: Can you add an example on how you're using this object?

Comment: Just like any associative javascript object, I've added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use child objects:

```
locales = {
    'A string': {
        context1: 'My localized string',
        context2: 'My localized string in another context'
    },
    'Another string': 'Another localized string'
};
```

Another option would be to have different locales, per context:

```
context1Locale = { ... };
context2Locale = { ... };
locale = { ... };
```

Then, use something like:

```
var str = context1Locale[key] || locale[key];
```

Comment: The context being optional, isn't it too verbose in this case? How to manage non-contextualized strings in this model?

Comment: @Guid: I added an alternative to my answer.

Comment: contextes are sentences too, and are dynamically defined by the user, I cannot create as many objects as I have sentences. But in JavaScript, I can have an empty string as a key, so, when context is missing, I can use '' as a key. Anyway, thanks.